# how to combine multiple IF in ms excel

Tags: excel

Is there a way that I can combine this formula in excel ?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("UC_",CODE!B7)), "UC", "Not Defined")
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("RC_",CODE!B7)), "RC", "Not Defined")
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("OC_",CODE!B7)), "OC", "Not Defined")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("UC_",CODE!B7)), "UC", IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("RC_",CODE!B7)), "RC", IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("OC_",CODE!B7)), "OC", "Not Defined")))
```

Comment: You should wait 24 hours before marking any one answer as correct - there may be other possibilities...

Comment: I disagree. Just because other possibilities might exist, does not mean that one has to wait before marking an answer (that is correct) as correct.

Comment: @Shazu Just to note that that is the advice of others (apart from me) who measure their reputation above 10,000 ... so take it or leave it...

Answer (score 1):

You may find this easier to use :

```
=MID(A1,FIND("C_",A1,1)-1,2)
```

[image]

It is much shorter and therefore less prone to error and will automatically deal with other codes of the same format such as "GC_" or "MC_" which a hard-coded solution won't...

You can put an iferror() around it:

```
=IFerror(MID(A1,FIND("C_",A1,1)-1,2),"check")
```